# Put every 5 Repeater items between a div

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater, itemdatabound

I'd like to get my items who are in my repeater get between a div
and after 5 elements in a new div.

So what i currently got is this:

View:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void DatesRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        var data = (Components.Models.GetDatesModel)e.Item.DataItem;

        var chk = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("eventDateCheckbox");
        chk.Text = data.EventTimeBegin.ToString();

        var hfd = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("eventID");
        hfd.Value = data.eventID.ToString();
    }
}
```

And i'd like to display it like this on the view:

```
<div class="column">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
    <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>            
</div>
```

How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Repeater PreRender event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).

Here's how the aspx code should look like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DatesRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DatesRepeater_ItemDataBound" 
    OnPreRender="DatesRepeater_PreRender">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltDivPrefix" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
        <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p> 
        <asp:Literal ID="ltDivSuffix" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The expected result is the following:

1. The text of `ltDivPrefix` will be `<div class="column">` for nth item where n % 5 equals 0, otherwise it will be empty.
2. The text of `ltDivSuffix` will be `</div>` for nth item where n % 5 equals 4, or n is the last index, otherwise it will be empty.

The total number of items can be obtained in `PreRender` event, so do a looping through the Repeater items and set the text of `ltDivPrefix` and `ltDivSuffix` according to the item index:

```
protected void DatesRepeater_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DatesRepeater.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        Literal ltDivPrefix = (Literal)DatesRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("ltDivPrefix");
        Literal ltDivSuffix = (Literal)DatesRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("ltDivSuffix");

        if ((i) % 5 == 0)
        {
            ltDivPrefix.Text = @"<div class=""column"">";
        }

        if ((i % 5 == 4) || (i == DatesRepeater.Items.Count - 1))
        {
            ltDivSuffix.Text = "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ment adding 5 checkboxes into one div, it has to figure out when to put it into a new div. Sorry my bad.

Comment: No, the amount of events are dynamic. After 5 events (checkboxes) it needs to be added in a new column. Not the same one.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know i had to use the pre-render function for this!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't introduce the `div` to the template?

```
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="column">
       <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="eventID" />
       <p><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="eventDateCheckbox" /></p>
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
```